# Is it possible to optimize the code fragment?

Tags: swift, swift3

I am new to Swift, and I have the following code fragment which I feel can be re-written in a more nice way, but I cannot realize how.

```
    let defaultCountry: MyEnum = ....
    let countryStr: String? = ....

    // How can I optimize the fragment below?
    let country: MyEnum
    if let countryStr = countryStr {
        country = MyEnum(rawValue: countryStr) ?? defaultCountry
    }
    else {
        country = defaultCountry
    }
```

Do anyone have an idea how to make it better, ideally in one line:

```
    let country = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flatMap(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) on your `Optional<String>` `countryStr`.

```
let country = countryStr.flatMap({ MyEnum(rawValue: $0) }) ?? defaultCountry
```

Answer (score 2):

There you have it in one line, just use the rawValue from the default enum value:

```
let country = MyEnum(rawValue: countryStr ?? defaultCountry.rawValue) ?? defaultCountry
```

Other approach:

```
var country = defaultCountry
if let validCountryStr = countryStr, let validCountryEnum = MyEnum(rawValue: validCountryStr) {
    country = validCountryEnum
}
```